# Сравнение числа с поля ввода, выводить сообщение на страницу

Tags: javascript

Посмотрите где у меня ошибка в  коде, который будет проверять введенное значение, и говорить, сдали вы тест или нет.

```js
function somefunc(){
  var test = document.getElementById('test').value;
  if (test > 64) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Pozdravlyaem";
  } else (test < 65) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="povtorite";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title>Знакомство с JavaScript</title>
       
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Сколько процентов вы набрали в экзамене?</p>
      <input id="test" type="text">
      <button type="button" onclick>Check it</button>
      <span id="text"> </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `else if (...)` а не `else (...)`

Comment: `onclick="somefunc()"` ...

Comment: `....innerHTML = (test > 64) ? "Pozdravlyaem" : "povtorite";` - - всё условие if-else можно подменить на это, кстати.